# Unable to add 20 "points" for reward program for above 3 beverages

Tags: java

I'm trying to add 20 "points" for every beverage (or drink) that a customer had the previous week for a rewards program after 3 beverages. However, I can't seem to add 20 points for every beverage past 3. It just adds 20 additional points, and then stops adding after that.

For example, if a customer had 4 beverages last week, then they should have 50 reward points; 70 reward points for 5 beverages, 90 points for 6 beverages, and so on. What my program is currently doing (or has done) is gone to 50 or 70 and then stayed the same (it's at 50 currently), no matter the number inserted, it's gone negative and subtracts 20, or infinitely loops without a break.

The numbers 1-3 are already taken for having 5 points, 15 points, and 30 points, respectively.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedDevilCoffeeRewards 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user how many beverages (or drinks) they bought last week
        System.out.println("How many beverages did you purchase last week");

        // Allows user input for amount of beverages bought last week
        int beverages = scanner.nextInt();
        int beverages4 = 50;
        int beveragesaddpoints = 20;
        int beveragepointtotal = beverages4 + beveragesaddpoints;
        //int beveragesmorethan4= beverages4 + 20;

for (int beverages4orhigher = beveragepointtotal; beverages4 >= 4; ++beverages4)
        {
            if (beverages >= 4)
            {
                beveragepointtotal += beveragesaddpoints;
                System.out.println("You have earned " + beverages4 + " points");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what if input is 3 ? , then no beverages point or 30 beverage point and from 4th beverage, it will be 50 points

Comment: Hi Gurkirat,
Are you saying that the number in the if statement should be 3?
I just wanted to clarify.
1-3 are already being used for a certain amount of points already, but that's good thinking, though.

Comment: I'm asking in case, the beverage consumed last week is less than or equal to 3, is there any reward in that case ?

Comment: Hi again Gurkirat
No, its for a coffee shop, where if you have 1 beverage, it's # of points, 2 beverage is 10 more points (15 total), 3 beverages, is 15 more points (30 total), and anything after is 20 additional points each. 
I'm sorry if I wasn't clear on that before.
Also, do you know if there's a way I can tag on here. I only joined very recently, so I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.

Comment: then for 6 coffees, it will be 75 and not 90 as you have mentioned in the sample output, right?
first 3 , 3*5 = 15 
remaining 3 , 3*20 = 60 
total = 75

Comment: you can use @ for tagging

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, so thanks for letting me know.

Comment: So basically 50 + max(0, numberOfBeverages - 5) * 20? Why use a loop at all? And to find out why your code breaks out of your loop, use a debugger and step through your program

Comment: Hi @knittl,

I was able to figure it out, and didn't see your comment right away.
Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the for loop that you have mentioned. You have declared a variable `beverages4orhigher` which is not used in the loop and then you are breaking out of the loop based on the beverages value which will be always be true in case the value is more than 4.

ii) You are printing the value of beverages4 and not beverageinTotal that should be printed.

You need to rectify these 2 changes.

```
   public class RedDevilCoffeeRewards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Ask user how many beverages (or drinks) they bought last week
        System.out.println("How many beverages did you purchase last week");

        // Allows user input for amount of beverages bought last week
        int beverages = scanner.nextInt();
        int beverages4 = 50;
        int beveragesaddpoints = 20;
        int beveragepointtotal = beverages4 + beveragesaddpoints;
        // int beveragesmorethan4= beverages4 + 20;
        int points = 0;
        if (beverages == 1) {
            points = 5;
        } else if (beverages == 2) {
            points = 15;
        } else if (beverages == 3) {
            points = 30;
        } else {
            points = 30;
            beveragepointtotal = beverages - 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < beveragepointtotal; i++) {
                points += 20;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("You have earned " + points + " points");
    }
}
```

and the sample output is

```
How many beverages did you purchase last week
6
You have earned 90 points
```

Comment: I forgot to say this originally, but the numbers 1-3 are already taken for having 5 points, 15 points, and 30 points, respectively, so I'm adding 20 points onto the 30 points already there, and then adding 20 additional for every beverage after that.
Sorry for not saying this earlier.

Also, when I tried to tag your name, it just disappeared, so you might get tagged twice as I thought the first time that it vanished, it was just a glitch.

Comment: @Mario have updated the code, please check if this helps

Comment: Okay, so it's adding 20 additional points each past 3, but the points for 1-3 are off, unfortunately, so I put in my code for 1-3, which then fixed the numbers for 1-3, but then broke your code for >=4, so now I'm not entirely sure on what to do.

Comment: @Mario in case beverage entered is 1 , then output should be 5, beverage entered is 2, then output should be 20 (or 15 )and beverage entered is 3, then output should be 50  ( or 30 ) , please clarify

Comment: Yes, for 1 beverage, you get 5 points total, 2 beverages are 15 points total, 3 beverages are 30 points total, and any beverages beyond that is 20 additional points each.
I'm very sorry for not clarifying this in the first place.

Comment: @Mario , please share the input for which you are geting wrong answer .

Comment: It looks like it's working completely. For some reason, when I refreshed the page earlier after you corrected, it still was on the original code, and not the revised code.
Thank You So Much; I Really Appreciate It.